Any potential pitfalls in implementation of debounce if we invoke the function normally instead of 'apply'?
We often find the debounce implementation with  func.apply(this, args) I guess this is just to make sure the 'this' points to the context of the inner function that's returned.


const debounce = function (func, wait = 1000) {
    let timer = null;

    return function (...args) {
      clearTimeout(timer);

      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        func.apply(this, args)
      }, wait);
    };
  };
  
  const handleSearch = function(param1, param2){
     console.log(param1 + param2);
  }
  
  let debouncedFunc = debounce(handleSearch, 1000);
  debouncedFunc("hello ", "world");



But what if we simply invoke the function with args without worrying about apply or this I get the same results. So is there any potential pitfalls with this approach due to which we generally implement like the former?


     const debounce = function (func, wait = 1000) {
        let timer = null;

        return function (...args) {
          clearTimeout(timer);

          timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func(...args)
          }, wait);
        };
      };
      
      const handleSearch = function(param1, param2){
         console.log(param1 + param2);
      }
      
      let res = debounce(handleSearch, 1000);
      res("hello ", "world");




Correct, this in the debounce does nothing.  It's likely done this way for legacy reason before arg spreading was available.  Putting this or undefined would have done the same because this of the anonymous callback is just undefined anyway, and this is shorter than saying undefined.. :)

@Keith That makes sense. Thank you.

@Keith const myObj = { data: 42,  increment: debounce(function() { this.data++; }, 100) }  1. using this 2. not using this (also, only doesn't throw an error because it's in sloppy mode).

@VLAZ  yeah, good point.  I was mainly comparing in the OP's case were he's not binding the function to an object, never even thought about binding the debounce to an object.  Also it now makes sense why the timeout uses an arrow function to keep the this context.

You lose the access to this. This can be crucial when you want to debounce methods in an object which try to access data from the object.
Consider the following example of a simple counter with debounced incrementation:
const counter = { 
  data: 41, 
  increment: debounce(function() { 
    this.data++; 
  }, 100)
}

When using .apply(this, args)1 this works exactly as expected:


const debounce = function (func, wait = 1000) {
  let timer = null;

  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args)
    }, wait);
  };
};

const counter = { 
  data: 41, 
  increment: debounce(function() { 
    this.data++; 
  }, 100)
}

counter.increment(); //increment call is debounced and will apply in 100ms
counter.increment(); //second call is within the debounce period, thus ignored

setTimeout(
  //the number printed is 42
  () => console.log(`after debounce period: ${counter.data}`),
  150
);



When not supplying the value of this to the debounced function, the result is off:


const debounce = function (func, wait = 1000) {
  let timer = null;

  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args)
    }, wait);
  };
};

const counter = { 
  data: 41, 
  increment: debounce(function() { 
    this.data++; 
  }, 100)
}

counter.increment(); //increment call is debounced and will apply in 100ms
counter.increment(); //second call is within the debounce period, thus ignored

setTimeout(
  //the number printed is 41
  () => console.log(`after debounce period: ${counter.data}`),
  150
);



In strict mode, the same code will even throw an error since this will be undefined:


"use strict";

const debounce = function (func, wait = 1000) {
  let timer = null;

  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args)
    }, wait);
  };
};

const counter = { 
  data: 41, 
  increment: debounce(function() { 
    this.data++; 
  }, 100)
}

counter.increment(); //increment call is debounced and will apply in 100ms
counter.increment(); //second call is within the debounce period, thus ignored

setTimeout(
  //the number printed is 41
  () => console.log(`after debounce period: ${counter.data}`),
  150
);



1 As a side note, it is probably easier to use .apply(this, arguments) - no need for varargs, as the arguments object already provides them. But it does not have much of an impact, overall.

Nice answer!!..  When OP originally posted, I had a inclination it was object instance related, but didn't think about just assigning the function to an object..

@VLAZ thanks didn’t think about this scenario. Thanks for highlighting this. Nice answer.
